# Mysql error 1054 in When statement

Tags: mysql, database, database-migration

Doing an inventory migration to a new schema. The old schema had one table, where the new schema has two and a foreign key linking the types of assets. Problem is with the foreign key part. I can't seem to get the foreign key to post on the asset table. I mostly have the logic figured out, but I'm running into an issue where the migration hits a 1054 error on a column that should exist.
Part throwing error is the " SELECT CASE WHEN (`asset`.`category` " bit.

```
ALTER TABLE `foreignkeytest`.`asset` 
    ADD COLUMN `category` VARCHAR(255) NULL AFTER `parent_asset_id_asset_id`,
    ADD COLUMN `subcategory` VARCHAR(255) NULL AFTER `category`,
    ADD COLUMN `brand` VARCHAR(255) NULL AFTER `subcategory`,
    ADD COLUMN `model` VARCHAR(255) NULL AFTER `brand`;
ALTER TABLE `foreignkeytest`.`asset_type`;
ALTER TABLE `inventory`.`inv`;
INSERT IGNORE INTO `foreignkeytest`.`asset` 
    (asset_id, category, subcategory, location, serial_number, brand, model, purchase_date, glacct, barcode_attached) 
    SELECT id, category, subcategory, location, serialnumber, brand, itemtype, from_unixtime(purchasedate), glacct, barcode 
    FROM `inventory`.`inv`;
INSERT IGNORE INTO `foreignkeytest`.`asset_type` (category, subcategory, brand, model) 
    SELECT category, subcategory, brand, itemtype FROM `inventory`.`inv`;
INSERT INTO `foreignkeytest`.`asset` (asset_type_id)
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN (`asset`.`category` = `asset_type`.`category` AND
                `asset`.`subcategory` = `asset_type`.`subcategory` AND
                `asset`.`brand` = `asset_type`.`brand` AND
                `asset`.`model` = `asset_type`.`brand`) THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
    type_id FROM `foreignkeytest`.`asset_type`;
ALTER TABLE `foreignkeytest`.`asset` DROP COLUMN `category`, DROP COLUMN `subcategory`, DROP COLUMN `brand`, DROP COLUMN `model`;
```

Any reason why this wouldn't be working?

Edit: Fix for this issue was that I wasn't referencing the `asset` table for the select. Second to last line changed to:

```
type_id FROM `foreignkeytest`.`asset_type`, `foreignkeytest`.`asset`;
```

Comment: Do you have an index on your the columns you are referencing with your foreign key?

Comment: I'm generating the foreign key through hibernate, and am not terribly familiar with MySQL having only just started this project around last week.
However, the engine is InnoDB, so correct me if I'm wrong, but the index is auto-generated, is it not?

Comment: what is the name of the column that create the error?

Comment: Ah, yes, do not migrate a database through any ORM.
Good job in isolating the current code though: You have to have indexes in place on the foreign keys, so find those and add an index.

Comment: @scaisEdge The column name is correct in the code. `category`

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen I'm only creating the tables via Hibernate. I'm migrating via Flyway.

Comment: Ok, the remark stays the same; You are missing an index on a referenced foreign key column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  are referring to asset table but you are selecting  from  foreignkeytest
so the case column are wrongs try select from asset

```
    INSERT INTO `foreignkeytest`.`asset` (asset_type_id)
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN (`asset`.`category` = `asset_type`.`category` AND
                `asset`.`subcategory` = `asset_type`.`subcategory` AND
                `asset`.`brand` = `asset_type`.`brand` AND
                `asset`.`model` = `asset_type`.`brand`) THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
    type_id FROM `asset`.`asset_type`;
```

Comment: Not quite, but you pointed me the right way. Change that worked was added to OP. Now I've got a different issue, though.